# Recurrence relation of the following function

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, recurrence

I'm trying to determine the recurrence relation of the following recursive function..I think I have done it correctly but would like some input on my method of solving..

```
Solve for C(n) the number of additions that this function does:
  //precondition: n>0
 int fct (const int A[], int n) {
      if (n==1)
         return A[0]*A[0];
      else return A[n-1] * fct(A,n-1) * A[n-1];
 }
```

Here, there are exactly two additions that occur as well as a recursive call for n-1.
C(1)=1
C(n)=2+C(n-1) //2 because of the number of additions plus the recursive call C(n-1)

Therefore

C(2)=C(1)+2=1+3=3
C(3)=C(2)+2=2+3=5
C(4)=C(3)+2=7
C(n)=2n-1

where big o is O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

Correct.  Keep in mind the structure of the recursive function depends on n:

```
int addRec(int A[], int n) {
```

The additions are otherwise constant time, so you are performing a constant operation n times, which results in the O(n) time complexity you got.